# atleast one active class when dynamic tabs are removed inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'll try to be specific as possible. I have a navbar which can have dynamically added tabs, upon clicking for additional tab, these additional tabs can also be removed by clicking on close button. Here's the Html:

```
<ul id="nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs" >
 <li id="test"  class="active">
  <a href="#home" data-toggle="tabs" >
   <img src="assets/img/button_home_selected3.png" class="hover" width="83" />
    <span>Home<button type="button" class="close">&times;</button></span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The li tags are dynamically added and removed, the active class in li tag shows different images making the tabs differentiable, thus the active class toggles between the li tags.

To close the tabs the script is:

```
$('.close').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
 $("#tab" + panelId).remove();
});
```

I just want atleast one active tab even when the active tab is removed by the user. Currently, when i close the active tab, there is no active class, making the tabs similar.

Comment: Please post some code may be how you are closing it

Comment: Post the closing code, so that we can meddle with it. :)

Comment: ok, i have posted the script to close the tabs

Comment: @Hunain Got it. Check if it works. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close the tab, take the index of the tab. If it's the last one, then add the active class to the last tab, if first, then first, if is somewhere in the middle, then take the one from the left or from the right of the closed tab.

```
$(".close").on("click", function() {
      var elem = $(this).closest("li");

      if (elem.hasClass("active")) {
          var idx = elem.index(),
              remainingTabs = $("li");

          if (idx <= remainingTabs.length) {
              $(remainingTabs.get(idx - 1)).addClass("active");
          } else if (idx == 0) {
              $(remainingTabs.get(0)).addClass("active");
          }
      }

      // remove current tab
      $(".close", elem).unbind();
      elem.remove();
}
```

Comment: this is only removing the button tag not the entire li tag containing everything

Comment: the same problem as the one mentioned below. your script is functioning but I have to mouseover the li tag to make it visible, although it is showing active in the debugger....

Comment: then your problem is in css

Comment: can anyone solve this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907997/show-dynamically-added-navlinks-when-added-in-bootstrap-navbar

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.close').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
    $("#tab" + panelId).remove();
    $("#nav-tabs").children("li").last().addClass("active");
});
```

Replace the `.last()` with `.first()`, if you want the first tab to be active. :)

Comment: your code is working fine unless i click in the middle or all tags, i have to mouseover the tab to make it visible, although the debugger shows there is active class present :p

Comment: I don't get you. What is it happening?

Comment: your script is functioning but I have to mouseover the li tag to make it visible, as it is showing active in the debugger...